# What happens when $scope.$watch expression depends on multiple variables?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

If in my controller, I have something like:

```js
$scope.service = Service;

$scope.$watch('service.properties[service.selectedProperty]', function(newVal,oldVal){});
```

What happens here? Both `service.properties` and `service.selectedProperty` can change. Does the watch end up watching both `service.properties` and `service.selectedProperty`?

I have tested this and the watch seems to execute when either variable changes, which is what I want. I am wondering if there are any unintended consequences when using `.$watch` this way, and how it actually works.

Comment: learn `$watchCollections`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the watch end up watching both `service.properties` and `service.selectedProperty`?

In fact, it is watching *neither*, only the result of evaluating the expression as a whole. I explain:

Angular watches use a dirty checking principle: if the *expression* as a whole is evaluated to be something else than when it was last evaluated, a change has happened, and the associated handlers are run. *(This behaviour is more apparent when you use the form of `$watch` which takes a function as its first argument - returning the value to be watched.)*

That means that *technically* there could exist a situation where `service.properties[service.selectedProperty]` is evaluated the same as before, but `service.properties`, the associative object, **and** `service.selectedProperty`, the property key have both (or either of them) changed in the meantime - yet, the expression is evaluated to be the same. In such cases, the change event is not triggered.

For example, given:

```
var myObj = {
    a: 123,
    b: 123
};
var key = 'a';
```

the value of the *expression* `myObj[key]` will stay the same even if you change `key` to be `'b'` instead of `'a'`.

As long as the expression evaluates to be the same, from the viewpoint of angular, nothing has changed. And for most intents and purposes, nor should it matter to you - if it does, your watch expression is set up improperly, and you probably want to watch a more generic expression.

Comment: This is incorrect, the comparison is done by reference , so whenever `service.properties` changed, the reference to `service.properties[service.selectedProperty]` would also  change and fire the watch.  The only way it would act as you describe is if one passed a function which returned `service.properties[service.selectedProperty]` as the argument to `$watch`, which is not how the OP is using `$watch` here.  See in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope), 'inequality is determined according to reference inequality'

Comment: @aarosil the "reference inequality" in this case only means that equality is determined by the `!==` operator, so two objects will only be equal if they are indeed the same reference, and not just *equivalent* objects. (This does not affect primitive values.) This kind of equality is what I mean whenever I use the term that values are "the same", and as such, I don't think this is incorrect.